# How to solve this Keyerror - Colab

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, google-colaboratory, keyerror

I really need help to solve this problem!

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'RS'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3fe762d4d605> in <cell line: 17>()
     15 #SELEÇÃO DO ESTADO
     16 state = 'RS'
---> 17 estados = list(df[state].unique())
     18 
     19 #SELEÇÃO DA COLUNA

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3805             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3806                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3807             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3808             if is_integer(indexer):
   3809                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'RS'
```

I need the code to generate a graph through plotly!!

This is one of the first codes I try and I have little knowledge about it. I've tried to make several changes, but I think I really don't know what to do.

As you can see, the code is an attempt to transform data about covid-19 into a graph. It is part of the content of a class for the development of a Python project.

Comment: You sure the key `'RS'` exists?

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.columns)`? Are you sure RS is capitalized? Try with `df['rs']` (RS for Serbia?)

Comment: possiblity of cause of keyError may be beacuse of key not present in that dictionary or wrong key, in your case as mentioned in above 2 comments either 'RS' wont present or 'RS' maybe caseSensitive, Please do try printing it.